# I have to use a Form tag?

Tags: html

```
<p>paragraph 1<span>extra info 1</span><span>extra info</span></p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<a> link </a>

<button>accept</button>
<p>another paragraph</p>
```

Hi everyone, As you can see i have only one button, a pair of `<p>` tag, inside of then `<span>` tags and `<a>` tag. My question is if I have to use a form tag for that?

Comment: For doing what exactly?

Comment: first I have a form where the user enters data, then in a second step shows the user data entry for check and that's where I have a button with which you agree that the data is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless you are submitting the form with it. Best way to check if you can use an element anywhere is use a doctype and validate the html.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `form` element if and only if you wish to make the page work even when client-side scripting is disabled (or unsupported) in the browser.

So this really depends on the overall design. If the system has been designed robustly, so that it works without JavaScript too, then this phase should be robust, too, with a submit button in a form. If not, it’s irrelevant to be robust at this phase.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. 
For example, you can use javascript `window.location` in `onclick` attribute of.button.